# How do I stop my netbook from sleeping when I pull the power?

Tags: 11.04, laptop, power-management, sleep

When I'm using my computer and unplug it, I would rather not have it go into sleep mode which it currently does. How do I fix that?

A concrete example of this is the last time where I was actively Skyping someone, the power cable was pulled by accident as it was tangled around a chair that someone pulled out and the computer went into sleep mode so I had to slide the power button to get back to the login screen.

This is opposed to the normal behavior of sliding the power button which shows the "shut down the computer" dialogue.

I have a Samsung N150 and I'm running [natty](/questions/tagged/natty).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your situation, e.g. your hardware specification, your Ubuntu version and what exact state the computer is in when you pull the power plug.

Comment: @N.N. Updated with a concrete example, I'm running a fully updated Natty and have had this issue for as long as I can recall.

Comment: Are the settings for the power management correct? I would recommend looking into gnome-control-center (or whatever Setup-Tool you use) and take a look at the settings, when your netbook is not plugged in. It can be (although this is only a guess) that skyping, counts as being inactive, for the power management, since you don't use your mouse.

Comment: @Ewald The example with Skype was just one specific incident. I could be browsing the web or doing anything. My power settings seem fine, I've included screenshots though.

Comment: Ok - thx for the screenshots. I don't know if the computer goes into suspend after 2 minutes or 2 hours if it runs on battery. But you could simply try and change the time at "Put the computer to sleep when inactive for".

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/pm-powersave.log` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` to see why your laptop is sleeping. Could you have a problem with your battery?

Comment: See my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,